# Hola, estoy buscando colaboración para resolver un de javascript que dice que la consola arroje las palabras repetidas que "dijeron" dos personas

Tags: javascript

Ej:
Persona 1: "Leer, jugar, hacer, vender, comprar"
Persona 2: "Comprar, entretener, arreglar, programar, leer"
//Ahí tendría que aparecer en el console.log "Comprar, leer"
No sé como hacerlo. Conseguí hacerlo con letras pero de un solo string.
Esto fue lo que hice:

```
    function repetidos(palabras){
    if (!palabras || !palabras.length) return null;
    var first = contenido[0].split('');
    return first.filter(
      (c, i) =>
        first.indexOf(c) === i
        && contenido.every(x=> x.indexOf(c) >= 0));
  }
  
  var contenido= ["hola","piano","triangulo"];
  
  console.log(repetidos(contenido));
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! letras de un solo string.. seran cadenas de longitud 1???  y no era mas facil recorrer los dos array, y comparar una a una cada cadena, y si eran iguales guardars en otra cadena?

Comment: ¿Cómo hago lo de comparar una por una?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion seria casi igual, solo tienes que pasar un array de arrays como parametro y quitar el `split`.  Algo asi:

```js
function repetidos(palabras){
    if (!palabras || !palabras.length) return null;
    var first = contenido[0];
    return first.filter(
      (c, i) =>
        first.indexOf(c) === i
        && contenido.every(x=> x.indexOf(c) >= 0));
  }
  
  var contenido= [["hola","piano","triangulo"],["hola","pelota","triangulo"]];
  
  console.log(repetidos(contenido));
```

Comment: Esto falla.. en su ejemplo dice Leer y leer.. son la misma palabra, pero no  son al comparar... y hubiera estado mejor explicar todo este codigo no?